# Need advice about Magento events

Tags: magento, observers

I created a module with a function inside Observer.php of said module. 
I want to run this script everytime there is a change inside the database regarding products but I can't find the right event to attach my observer, any tips?

Comment: what exactly you want to do and when ? be specific.!

Comment: The script itself is a little complicated: it creates an innerjoin table with various parameters so that I can change the value of a product's attribute depending on the status of the client it belongs.
ex.
Seller status: retailer - products: sellable /
Seller status: display - products: only display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really depends what changes you are looking for, but this one will catch most fundamental product changes;

```
catalog_product_save_before
```

or

```
catalog_product_save_after
```

Depending on what it is you need to achieve.

These cheat sheets from Nick Jones are well worth a look https://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-9/

Comment: No problem.  If this helped, kindly accept it as the answer